# Webpack not creating css and js files

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, webpack, vue.js

I am using Laravel and Vue.js. When I do NPM run dev my Sass files are not compiling and they are being created in `/public`. What can be the reason for that?
I can not show code because of NDA reasons.

Comment: How are you including the sass files? Any errors in the console? Did you install the proper loaders? You need to give a lot more information. Also, if the code isn't shareable cut it down to a minimal example. Also, running `npm run dev` wouldn't put anything into public automatically. It'll likely put things in there due to `npm run build`

Comment: Well at least.  You can post what error you are getting..

Answer (score 0):

Have you edited your `webpack.mix.js` file ?

By default, Laravel Mix will compile only the file `resources/assets/sass/app.scss`. Unless you tell Laravel Mix to compile your other SASS files or import them on the `app.scss` file, they will be ignored. The same goes for your javascript files.

To compile everything into one file, I set my `webpack.mix.js` like the following:

```
const { mix } = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');
const glob = require('glob');

mix.js(glob.sync('resources/assets/js/**/*.js'), 'public/js/app.js');
```

That way, every .js file that is inside your `resources/assets/js` folder, and the subfolders is glued together into a single file, that can be imported with ease into your html.